# How to solve Gephi error : cannot load even default layout (Installation step)

Tags: java, gephi

I would like to ask about the gephi since the gephi program does not work.
I have downloaded version 0.9.2 of Geph and Java JDK-16.0.1.

If I run Gephi after downloading it, it starts program however soon after error messages pop up.

1. cannot load even default layout, using internally predefined configuration
2. cannot load window system persistant data, user directory content is broken.Resetting to default.

I followed all the instruction which are in the tutorial page(https://gephi.org/users/install/) 
However I still got same errors.
And once I deleted user directory, it appear again.

Could somebody give me adive for this issue?

My computer sepecification is as follows.

1. Microsoft surface pro3
2. Windows 10 64bits
3. Intel(R) HD Graphics Family

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a Java version mismatch between the Java your computer uses, and the Java your Gephi uses.

Tested on Windows 10 (or 8 I don't remember, that was not my computer):

1. Download Java JRE 1.8 (I guess it also work with >1.8)
2. Set your JAVA_HOME environment variable such as:

`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre_1.8\bin`

(The real path might defer)

3. Gephi will not recognize java, because widnows needs the trailing `\bin` while Gephi does not. Go to yout Gephi configuration:

`C:\Program Files\Gephi\etc\gephi.conf`
(once again, I do not remember the exact path, not my pc)

Inside the file, there is a line :

```
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

Replace it by:

```
jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre_1.8"
```

Yes, I removed the # (that symbols tells Gephi to ignore the line). Yes, it is written "jdkhome" but as strange as it seems it will not work unless you write the jre path instead (as i did). Note that the path is the same that the one set as your JAVA_HOME, but with the trailing `\bin` removed.

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install Java 8 or 9.
then add path in configuration file and save.
run again..........

Answer (score 0):

As said above, it's a Java version mismatch between the Java your computer uses, and the Java your Gephi uses.
When I use JDK-17.x.x, it comes up with the same question.
Solve this problem by degrade to jdk-11.0.14.
It may need your oracle account to download the previous releases.